# Headers overwritten on redirect using Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, apache, http

I'm using Apache HttpComponents (core - 4.1.3, httpclient 4.1.1) to make http requests in a REST client I've written.  The web service requires OAuth, which I've implemented using signpost.  Recently, the webservice has introduced 301 redirects to endpoints that also require oauth.  So, I've implemented a custom RedirectStrategy which builds a new request and signs it with signpost, just like I would do normally.  However, the first two lines (in [DefaultRequestDirector](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector.html)) immediately after I return my new request are setting all the headers to those that were sent in the initial request, effectively wiping my new Authorization header and causing all redirect requests to fail.

Does anyone know a way around this?  I've considered always returning false in my custom [RedirectStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy.html) and handing this in the [ResponseHandler](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler.html) that I've attached to my request, but there's no trivial way of reconstructing the request and submitting it back through the proper client.

These are lines 1021-1023 in the DefaultRequestDirector where it calls to my custom RedirectStrategy and then wipes my headers (I'll try to link to source, shortly):

```
HttpUriRequest redirect = redirectStrategy.getRedirect(request, response, context);
HttpRequest orig = request.getOriginal();
redirect.setHeaders(orig.getAllHeaders());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here, but if the code that you are referring to is line [349 of `DefaultRequestDirector`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.1.1/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector.java), then a bit further down on line 452 there is a call to `requestExec.preProcess(wrapper, httpProcessor, context)`.

Would it be possible to register a processor here that signs the request?

If not, the [`BasicHttpProcessor`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/tags/4.1.3/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpProcessor.java) (which is probably the processor used here) allows you to register interceptors that allow you to participate in the pre-processing of the request.

This might be another option to sign the request.

Alternatively, there is a [`HttpContext`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/tags/4.1.3/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.java) object. The Javadoc for this object suggests that it can be used to hold contextual data for the request, and your data would fit this description. So park it there and regather when you need it later.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I spent some time trying to implement a RequestInterceptor and by the time the request gets there, the uri that signpost uses to sign the request has been stripped down to just what comes after the domain where it's expecting the fully qualified uri.  I suppose I could make a copy of the intercepted request (with a full uri) and then copy the Authorization header over to the intercepted request.  However, I'm worried about a performance hit.  Plus, that just seems really hacky.

Comment: Yeah you might not be able to put it in the request itself, you might have to put it to one side and then apply it later. There is a HttpContext object, is that not what it's there for? The Javadoc seems to suggest so - https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/tags/4.1.3/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.java.

Comment: Brilliant!  Why didn't I think of that?  Can you edit your answer and add this comment so I can mark it as solved?  Thanks so much!